# Java Script - array of className - Perform an action into one array element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of `ClassName`:

```
Starter = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonsColor');
```

and 3 buttons:

```
<.button class="buttonsColor" type="button" 
 onclick="starterMenu()";>Starter</button>
 <.button class="buttonsColor" type="button" onclick="menuM()";>Main</button>
 <.button class="buttonsColor" type="button" 
onclick="menuDessert()";>Dessert</button>"
```

When I want to change the color of one of the elements in this array I must turn to it and give its index to 0, 1 or 2 for example in this case.

How can I do this so that when I click on one of the three buttons then I will know that I clicked on it and then it will be possible to perform actions such as changing the color, etc?

Maybe use in `addEventListener`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Before we can help you, we're going to need you to do some of your own research. If you think `addEventListener` can help, try reading up on it and experimenting a while. If you get stuck on a specific problem, post what you tried and then we can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this so that when I click on one of the three buttons
>   then I will know that I clicked on it and then it will be possible to
>   perform actions such as changing the color, etc.

*Below are examples on how you might bind a click event handler and how you might interact with the styles of a clicked button. It should get you started allowing you to expand from there.*

To select the buttons by class you can select them just as you have shown:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonsColor');
```

You can now iterate through the buttons and using [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) attach the click event handler similar to this:

```
for(var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', yourClickHandler);
}
```

If you now want to change the color of the clicked button you can do that by adding a class to the button's [**classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) that applies the style, similar to:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonsColor');

var changeColor = function(){
  this.classList.add('active');
};

for(var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Starter</button>
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Main</button>
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Dessert</button>
```

If you wish to toggle the color you can do that using `.classList.toggle(active)`

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonsColor');

var changeColor = function(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
};

for(var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Starter</button>
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Main</button>
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Dessert</button>
```

If you want to make the selection mutual exclusive you can do that by removing the class from all buttons using `classList.remove(active)` and only assign it to the clicked button, again, using `classList.add(active)`

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonsColor');

var changeColor = function(){
  for(var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  this.classList.add('active');
};

for(var i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Starter</button>
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Main</button>
<button class="buttonsColor" type="button">Dessert</button>
```